# how to use remote redis server without installing it to development PC

Tags: redis

I am using redis server.
I have installed it on a PC having IP address 192.168.10.38. When I connect using the same PC redis servre is working fine.

Now my actual problem is I want to connect with same server using another PC.
Note that redis server is not installed to this PC.

When I use the same application on this another PC, I am getting exception below.

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:142) ~[jedis-2.4.2.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:75) ~[jedis-2.4.2.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1724) ~[jedis-2.4.2.jar:?]
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:65) ~[jedis-2.4.2.jar:?]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:819) ~[commons-pool2-2.0.jar:2.0]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:429) ~[commons-pool2-2.0.jar:2.0]
at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360) ~[commons-pool2-2.0.jar:2.0]
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40) ~[jedis-2.4.2.jar:?]
```

Kindly help me with this and let me know can I use remote redis server without installing it to my development PC ?

Comment: Would it be safe to assume you've checked firewall settings?

Comment: Default port is 6379, but if I remember correctly you can change it. So check your firewall, open the port or change redis configuration.

Comment: Yes, I checked my firewall settings and everything is fine there. Also 6379 is already open.I am searching and found that redis is binding 6379 on 127.0.0.1 which might be the reason, but not sure, still searching.

Answer (score 1):

Redis server is by default binded to 127.0.0.1

I changed it to 0.0.0.0 and finally it uses 0.0.0.0:6379 to listen redis server services.

And it worked for me.